# Is K unfaithful too his youth love / love interest from MiB in MiB 3?

Tags: plot-explanation, men-in-black-3

In the first Men In Black movie it is made quite clear that K is still in love with the girl he left behind which he had to abandon to be a Man In Black.

But in MiB he flirts heavily with Agent O, even though the incident with the girl he left behind must not have been long ago. J even makes snide remarks about it.

From a narrative point, this plot line makes K look more human in MiB3 and adds a subplot with a love interest, but it completely disregards K's personality from MiB1.

Can it be assumed that the screenwriters just disregarded K's History to have a love interest in MiB3? Is K unfaithful too his youth love / love interest from MiB in MiB 3?

Comment: 1) the girl he left behind? It's Agent O (watch it again and listen out for the banter that they exchange when Agent J wakes up at K's desk at MiB head quarters) 2) K is a stickler for the rules, when he is told that there is to be no fraternising, he doesn't fraternise. Even to his own detriment

Comment: @JamieTaylor no the girl he left behind is from the first movie, the one he has to leave in order to become an agent. He stalks her for the rest of her life and is reunited with her afte he leaves the mib.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He could have ended his relationship with the woman from the first movie and joined the MIB.

In working with Agent O they developed a mutual attraction that was never acted upon, however that doesn't mean he no longer had feelings for the woman he left. It could have been his attraction to O was just to help deal with the loss of the other woman.

Having realized that a relationship with a fellow Agent was either not allowed or a bad idea he returned to viewing O as a colleague and eventual superior (i.e. he "Friendzoned" her) this would have allowed his feelings for the woman he left to resurface and since having emotional attachment to her would have little to no impact on his abilities as an Agent he continued to follow her as he did in the first movie.